# What is a pointer of int data type pointing at if is a private data member of a class and we create two objects of that class?

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, debugging

I have a class for a sparse matrix. Say it has a pointer `a` of int data type as a private data member. My question then is, if I create two objects `B` and `C` of that class, would both `B` and `C` have a pointer `a` pointing to the same location or they would do something else?

I am confused here.

---

The *actual* pointer in my class is defined as a private member thus:

```
element* ele;
```

and it's assigned in the constructor with:

```
ele = new element[this->num_non_zero];
```

Comment: Depends on the implementation. Look at the *copy constructor* and *copy assignment operator*.

Comment: It depends completely on the code. By default the copy constructor will make the two pointers point at the same location. If you want something different then you have to write your own copy constructor instead of using the default. Same thing goes for the assignment operator.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov i have not created a copy constructor and i guess it is not even required as i don't want the objects to have same value for data members.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan Thats precisely the wrong way round. If you don't want the pointers to have the same value, then you do need to write a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we can see the code you're discussing, the pointer you have is declared and initialised (in the constructor) in the following manner:

```
Element *ele;
ele = new element[this->num_non_zero];
```

That use of `new` gives each instance their *own* copy of memory to which their own `ele` variable points to. There is no possibility of different instances interfering with each other given this method.

Below is the original answer, before you added the deail allowing us to succinctly answer your question. Since it provides interesting background information, I've left it in.

---

Unless the member variable is a class-level static (shared amongst all instances of the class), it belongs to the instance itself, and will point to wherever it's set to (possibly, but not necessarily, in a constructor).

See, for example, the following code, which has both a static and non-static member variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class demo {
public:
    demo(int newnonstat = 7, int newstat= 42): nonstat(newnonstat) {
        std::cout << "create\n";
        stat = newstat;
    }
    void dump(std::string desc) {
        std::cout << desc << ": " << nonstat << ' ' << stat << '\n';
    }
private:
    int nonstat;
    static int stat;
};
int demo::stat;

int main() {
    demo d1; d1.dump("d1");
    demo d2(1, 2); d2.dump("d2"); d1.dump("d1");
}
```

The output of that shows that the possibilities for how the two types are set (with my added comment):

```
create
d1: 7 42
create
d2: 1 2
d1: 7 2 <-- "corrupted" static
```

---

So, unless they're static, the variables will be distinct. However, as pointers, there's nothing that stops distinct pointers pointing to the same thing, it all comes down to what the various bits of code set it to.

Another example, with distinct pointers that point to the same thing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class demo {
public:
    demo(char *pStr) : m_pStr(pStr) {}
    void dump(std::string desc) {
        std::cout << desc << ": " << &m_pStr << ' ' << (void*)m_pStr << " '" << m_pStr << "'\n";
    }
private:
    char *m_pStr;
};

int main() {
    char buff[] = "same string";
    demo d1(buff);
    demo d2(buff);

    d1.dump("d1");
    d2.dump("d2");
}
```

The output shows the pointers, although distinct (second column is address of pointer variable), pointing to the same thing (third and fourth column):

```
d1: 0x7ffea260c150 0x7ffea260c18c 'same string'
d2: 0x7ffea260c158 0x7ffea260c18c 'same string'
```

Comment: No, the member variable ain't static. So I assume that you are saying B and C will have separate copies of 'a'  pointing at different locations.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan: they have separate *pointers,* yes. But nothing stops them from pointing to the same address. It's all down to what you set them to.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan He's not saying anything like that at all. You seem quite determined to believe this incorrect information.

Comment: @john No mate it's not like that i am determined to believe anything whether wrong or right, it's just that i started c++ recently, and i think that i kind of always mess up my code because of some basic details.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan OK, well understand that if you want a pointer member to have its value modified when the object is copied then you need to write a copy constructor to do that modification. It doesn't happen automatically. Same point for the assignment operator as well.

Comment: @john: exactly right. Default copy construct is what we call a shallow one. It just copies each member variable value as-is. If one of those member variables is a pointer, you'll end with two instances of the class pointing at the same thing. An explicit copy constructor (a deep one) will fix this.

Comment: @john this thing is confusing me a bit, because i am not copying Object C from B, i am creating  them separately by passing different parameters.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan I think to explain what's going on I'd need to see the code. Depending on how the code is written you could either end up with the same pointer or with different pointers. Both are possible.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan: John and you are both right. If you're not copying, the copy constructor doesn't come in to it. But then it comes down to what's in the *regular* constructor. I've tried to provide some examples showing different things but it may be worthwhile attaching your actual code to the question so we don't have to guess :-)

Comment: @ArthurMorgan, I've just noticed you provided that info in an answer. An addition to the question would have been a better approach, so I've moved the relevant information to there, and updated this answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes it would have been much better.It's just that i have created my account today itself so i am unfamiliar with the interface..